# Minimum Surface Water for Plate Tectonics?

Tags: plate-tectonics, planetary-science, hydrogeology

There is good evidence that the presence of water on a planet's surface is necessary for that planet to have plate tectonics. My question is this: Do we know if there is a minimum amount of surface water that is needed to sustain this? How little water could a planet hypothetically have, yet still possess active plate tectonics?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a link to this good evidence had been very helpful when trying to answer this.

Comment: Sure thing! Here you go: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001AGUFM.U21A..09S

Comment: @Arkenstein - I wouldn't call a conference paper that has been cited one time  since it was published 17 years ago "good evidence".

Comment: Here are a few more: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012821X97001829 http://science.sciencemag.org/content/294/5542/578 As well as a refutation of the hypothesis: http://www.nature.com/articles/nature12193